# Game of Polite Chocolate

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

I'm starting to play around with some properties of combinatorial games, and I
am having problems formalizing an argument based around the game of polite
chocolate.

There is an $n \times m$ grid of chocolates, where each chocolate is labelled 
$c_{i,j}$ 
for being in row $i$, column $j$. When a given player takes the chocolate 
$c_{i,j}$, that player must take all chocolates
$c_{k,l}$ where $k \le i$ and $l \ge j.$ 
The idea being, given I take a chocolate, 
I must take all chocolates in the upper-right square from from the chocolate. 
The person who takes the chocolate $c_{n,1}$ loses.

Take this game simply with two players, where each player takes turns making
moves in the game.
I have a feeling that if player 1 has a winning strategy in the
case of the $n \times r$ board ($n$ columns, $r$ rows of chocolate) when
$n \gt 1 \wedge r \gt 1,$ and this is because if player $2$ has a winning strategy,
player $1$ can steal this given strategy. However, I am having difficulties
formalizing this argument. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove using a strategy stealing argument that player 1 has a winning strategy in the chomp game](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005388/prove-using-a-strategy-stealing-argument-that-player-1-has-a-winning-strategy-in)  The usual name of this game is Chomp.  If you search the site for it, you will find it.

Comment: http://www.whydomath.org/Reading_Room_Material/ian_stewart/chocolate/chocolate.html

Comment: The actual strategies are very interesting.  There is some discussion around page 598 of _Winning Ways_ by Elwyn R. Berlekamp, John H. Conway, and Richard K. Guy (Academic Press, New York 1982).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We show that Player 1 has a winning strategy except in the case of the $1\times 1$ chocolate bar. The game ends in no more than $mn$ moves, and ties are not possible, so one of the players has a winning strategy. We show it is Player 1, by using a strategy-stealing argument.

Suppose to the contrary that Player 2 had a winning strategy. Then Player 2 would have a winning response to Player $1$ taking the **top right square** on her first move.  But the result of that response can also be achieved in a first move by Player 1.